# How to get line and column by position in C#?

Tags: c#

Consider the following string:

```cs
var text = @"


Hello How
Are       You doing?
""MyNameIs:""
       XYY

";
```

How to get a character in any position (>=0) with a related column and line?

**position** means put all the characters in a row and then count them from zero like:

```
\n \n \n H e l l o ' ' H o  w  \n  A  r  e ...
0  1  2  3 4 5 6 7 8   9 10 11 12 13 14 15 ...
```

```cs
public CharInfo GetCharInfo(int position) // for example position 35
{
    // ???
    return new CharInfo(char, line, column);
}
```

[image]

Comment: See my updated answer! Also, be careful, you are not accounting for '\r' (at least on Windows, your verbatim string would contain NewLines rather than '\n', which are in fact "\r\n".)

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest and most efficient solution (in terms of memory and performance) which can also be easily adapted to streams rather than strings for large inputs:

```
    private static (int line, int column, char chr) GetCharFromPosition(string text, int pos)
    {
        var line = 0;
        var col = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= pos; i++)
        {
            if (text[i] == '\n')
            {
                line++;
                col = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                col++;
            }
        }

        return (line, col, text[pos]);
    }
```

Update after performance comparison. If you are that concerned with performance, and this is run on an in-memory string, this would be the way to go:

```
private static unsafe (int line, int column, char chr) GetFromPosUnsafe(string text, int pos)
{
    var line = 0;
    var col = 0;
    char c = '\0';
    char returnedChar = '\0';
    int strLength = text.Length;

    fixed (char* p = text)
    {
        var p1 = p;
        for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
        {
            c = *p1++;
            if (c == '\n')
            {
                line++;
                col = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                col++;
            }
            returnedChar = c;
        }
    }

    return (line, col, returnedChar);
}
```

Comment: this is not based on position, I have just position

Comment: Good point, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Split the string in to lines:

```
var lines = text.Split('\n');
```

Then you can access for example the 3rd line and the 4th column via

```
char result = lines[3][4];
```

(Assuming you start counting at zero)

**EDIT**: After you updated your question, this code might help you:

```
int position = 35;
string[] lines = text.Split('\n');
        int lineIndex = 0;
        int columnIndex = 0;
        foreach(string line in lines)
        {
            if(position < line.Length)
            {
                columnIndex = position;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                position -= line.Length + 1; // +1 because split removes the \n
            }
            lineIndex++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("line="+lineIndex);
        Console.WriteLine("column="+columnIndex);
        Console.WriteLine("char="+text[position]);
```

This gives you the character, its line and its column at position 35.

Comment: whar is the character, line, and column for position 35?

Comment: @HamedFathi your question was not clear that this is what you wanted :)

Comment: See my post again. Position means put all the characters in a row and then count them.

Answer (score 3):

```
    int indexToSearchfor = 35;
    string subString = text.Substring(0, indexToSearchfor);
    int line =  subString.Count(c=> c == '\n'); // Count the number of line breaks
    int row = subString.Length - subString.LastIndexOf('\n')-1; //Calculate number of chars since last line break, adjust of off-by-one error
    
    Console.WriteLine(line);
    Console.WriteLine(row);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/tbnh81

**Edit: updated after AlexandruClonțeas comment regarding performance**

Linq will almost never be the most optimized solution but really helps with readability. If we're concerned with performance, Span is great help.

```
ReadOnlySpan<char> text = Text.AsSpan().Slice(0,pos);
var e = text.GetEnumerator();
int r=0,c=0,n=0;
while(e.MoveNext()){
    if(e.Current == '\n'){
        r++;
        c=n;
    }
    n++;
}
return(r,pos-c-1);
```

Comparing this to my original answer using Linq and AlexandruClonțeas solution, woring on a 10Mb input file we get:

```
// * Summary *

BenchmarkDotNet=v0.12.1, OS=Windows 10.0.18363.900 (1909/November2018Update/19H2)
Intel Core i7-7700 CPU 3.60GHz (Kaby Lake), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=3.1.201
  [Host]     : .NET Core 3.1.3 (CoreCLR 4.700.20.11803, CoreFX 4.700.20.12001), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 3.1.3 (CoreCLR 4.700.20.11803, CoreFX 4.700.20.12001), X64 RyuJIT


|         Method |        Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
|--------------- |------------:|----------:|----------:|
|   TestWithLinq | 44,091.1 us | 649.20 us | 575.50 us |
|   TestWithSpan |    660.6 us |  11.95 us |   9.98 us |
| GetCharFromPos |  1,747.4 us |  21.54 us |  17.99 us |

// * Hints *
Outliers
  Test.TestWithLinq: Default   -> 1 outlier  was  removed (46.93 ms)
  Test.TestWithSpan: Default   -> 2 outliers were removed (703.07 us, 703.25 us)
  Test.GetCharFromPos: Default -> 4 outliers were removed (1.84 ms..2.87 ms)
```

Full gist can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/JC-85/44a7ce76de6fba72c1dc1d028b9b2abc

**Conslusion:** Comparatively Linq is pretty slow, but processing a 10Mb file still takes less than 50ms. If performance still is an issue for some reason, use Span.

**Edit** Speaking of optimizations, we should realize were aproaching the problem from the wrong direction. Starting from zero and counting up we need to keep track of both row and column since we don't know if we've passed the last line-break until we reach the the target pos.

If we instead start from target pos and move backwards, then we only need to keep track of column until we reach the nearest line break, after that we only need to increment the row-count until we reach the beginning.

```
private static unsafe (int, int) AreWeDoneYet (string text, int pos) {
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        fixed (char * p = text) {
            var p1 = p + pos;

            while ( * p1-- != '\n') col++;

            while (p1 >= p) {
                if ( * p1-- == '\n') row++;
            }
        }
        return (row, col);
    }
```

Comment: If you normalize the line endings, how would you get the real position in the original string? Also, a pretty smart solution though for finding the row and column.

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea Good catch!

Comment: @HamedFathi Please note that this does multiple "passes" of the string and does extra allocations :)

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea This is still O(n) so I wouldn't worry about it. But yeah, Linq will always be a trade-off from performance to readability.

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea Updated my answer with performance comparison.

Comment: And memory usage? :D

Comment: I've took your idea of counting line breaks from the first code snippet, but changed it to use only `String.IndexOf()` without creating sub string. This one seems to be faster than the other methods: https://gist.github.com/zett42/ad026f229bb69e54adeba61a7ab7d5c3

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and complete answer

```cs
public class CharLocation
{
    public CharLocation(char character, int line, int column)
    {
        Line = line;
        Column = column;
        Character = character;
    }
    public int Line { get; private set; }
    public int Column { get; private set; }
    public char Character { get; private set; }

}
    
public static CharLocation GetCharLocation(this string text, int position)
{
    string subString = text.Substring(0, position);
    string[] splitted = subString.Split('\n');
    int line = splitted.Length;
    int column = subString.Length - subString.LastIndexOf('\n') - 1;
    var character = splitted[line - 1][column - 1];
    return new CharLocation(character, line, column);
}
```

Comment: Note that for large strings, this does extra allocation and multiple passes of the string instead of one pass (see my updated solution). Easy != Efficient, and Complete == never (in general).